# Birthday eMailer app

Tags: workflow, email-template

I downloaded the Birthday eMailer app in mid-2014 so that we can send birthday emails to our customers. This year we wanted to refresh the look of the email that we send out so we created another template with a new look. I can't seem to figure out how to replace the previous template with the new template as the app's default template, though. Would someone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about this app:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003I77zEAC

It mentions that it is using Email Templates. Please have a look at the following page of the Salesforce documentation and let us know if you can find the Email Template to edit: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_emailtemplates.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Yes, that's the app I was referring to. I just want to know how to replace the email template that it uses when sending the message to our customers (let's call it "Happy Birthday") with a new template that uses a new design (let's call it "Birthday Greeting")? Just want to make sure that by the next time an automated birthday greeting is sent, the customer will already receive the new template with the new design.

Comment: The Salesforce documentation I refered to says:
*To access your email templates, do one of the following:
From Setup, click Communication Templates | Email Templates.
Click on the name of any email template to go to the Viewing Email Templates page.
To edit or delete a template, click Edit or Del next to the template name in the list.* - that should point you to where you can edit the template?